# How do I remove OneSignal?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, onesignal

I used cocoapods to install OneSignal into my xcode project, but now I want to remove it so I can go to Firebase instead(my ads are from google so I thought of just making life easier by using everything with google). How do I remove OneSignal completely from my Xcode project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to easily do it is to simply remove the line from your pod file and then run

```
pod install
```

from terminal.

However, if you want to compeltely start from scratch, use the cocoapods plugin deintegrate. You can get it from here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate or install it from terminal:

```
$ [sudo] gem install cocoapods-deintegrate
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: De-integrate is now a default plugin, so you can run `pod deintegrate` straight off the bat :+1: